# what to namespace in @PayloadRoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I am trying to understand what is namespace exactly means in payloadroot annotation i.e.

```
 @PayloadRoot(localPart = "orderRequest", namespace = "http://samples")
```

I have taken this piece of code from spring docs but I still don't understand what `http://samples` is or what it does and why we need it?

Answer (score 1):

The namespace value is intended to be a URI location which points to a `xsd/xml` schema by which you can validate the incoming value of the `@RequestPayload` request.